# The divergence of the stress-energy tensor vanishes; is this statement sufficient to derive the Einstein field equations?

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Can one derive the Einstein field equations from this statement alone?
$$0 =  T^{\mu\nu}{}_{;\nu} = \nabla_\nu T^{\mu\nu} = T^{\mu\nu}{}_{,\nu} + \Gamma^{\mu}{}_{\sigma\nu}T^{\sigma\nu} + \Gamma^{\nu}{}_{\sigma\nu}T^{\mu\sigma}.$$

Comment: What makes you think so?

Answer (score 0):

No because this tells you nothing about the geometry of space. Since the divergence of the stress-energy tensor vanishes  for any geometry, it can't provide any information about the spacetime.

Moreover, the simplest counterexample would be the Einstein field equations in empty space where no matter or energy exist. There are still going to be non-trivial solutions, but since the stress-energy tensor will be 0, its divergence being also 0 doesn't provide you with any information.